# How to find the most common group of players

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to find the frequency or count of player compositions using SQL. Here is my dataset

```
event key                   team_id player_id
12235384031441051453625936  1       27
12235384031441051453625936  1       11
12235384031441051453625936  1       42
12235384031441051453625936  1       15
12235384031441051453625936  1       6
12235384031441051453625936  2       30
12235384031441051453625936  2       35
12235384031441051453625936  2       9
12235384031441051453625936  2       6
12235384031441051453625936  2       28
12235384031441051453626082  1       14
12235384031441051453626082  1       28
12235384031441051453626082  1       27
12235384031441051453626082  1       9
12235384031441051453626082  1       6
12235384031441051453626082  2       11
12235384031441051453626082  2       27
12235384031441051453626082  2       42
12235384031441051453626082  2       15
12235384031441051453626082  2       6
```

So for each event, there players on team 1 and team 2, the player_ids represent a player. I have roughly 500 events, and a lot of these players will appear in multiple events, but not always with the same players. Every team will always have 5 players, and the event keys represent a game. So I basically have 500 of the dataset above.

I am trying to find the most common team composition. For example, using the dataset above, I see players 27,11,42,15,6 in event ending in 936 and event ending in 082. So based on THIS dataset, this team composition has a COUNT of 2.

I am trying to get an output that counts the amount of times a group of players appear in the same team together and I am struggling with coming up with a coherent statement that does this.

Comment: You need a better description of what you are doing.  Do you always want exactly five players?

Comment: Yes, it has to be 5 players. I'll clarify further in my original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the most common team composition is to use `listagg()` to bring the members together:

```
select players, count(*) as numevents
from (select listagg(player_id, ',') within group (order by player_id) as players
      from t
      group by eventkey, team_id
     ) p
group by players
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Ah, I think this does it. Thank you so mcuh.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I like in StackOverflow is to learn something from others problems. Because I liked this question and Gordon Linoff's answer (+1 for both), I'm posting the SQL Server version based on his answer, since I tried to reproduce it but there is no listagg on MSSQL. Who knows if it's helpful for someone who has the same problem but different DBMS.

**Table** (Without the large event IDs)

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (event_key INT, team_id INT, player_id INT)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,1,27);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,1,11);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,1,42);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,1,15);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,1,6);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,2,30);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,2,35);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,2,9);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,2,6);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,2,28);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,1,14);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,1,28);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,1,27);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,1,9);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,1,6);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,2,11);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,2,27);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,2,42);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,2,15);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (2,2,6);
```

**Code**

```
select players, count(*) as numevents
from (select stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST(player_id as nvarchar)
    FROM @t1 as t1
    WHERE t1.event_key=t2.event_key
    AND t1.team_id=t2.team_id
    ORDER BY player_id
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') as players
      from @t1 as t2
      group by event_key, team_id
     ) p
group by players
order by count(*) desc;
```